# Combining Bash Script and Script Resources into One Executable

Tags: bash, executable

When trying to execute a bash script, it is often execute inside some directory, and requires access to local resources. I was wondering if there was a way to combine both the bash script and the resources (everything else in the directory) into an executable, so that I would only need that executable stand-alone to execute the bash script.

Comment: `shar(1)` would be traditional, but why does it need to be a single executable, when you could instead use `rsync` or `git` or something to move a file tree around as needed?

Comment: For convenience. For example, when I want to run the script from /usr/local/bin, I don't want to move the whole directory to /usr/local/bin - I think it would be more convenient to move just the combined executable.

Comment: This sounds messy and fragile. You shouldn't be moving scripts around like that, and definitely not into directories owned by root, unless you know _exactly_ what you're doing. Why can't you just pass the directory you want the script to work on as a command-line argument? Are you aware of the `pwd` command? Also, you can store the name of the directory containing the resources your script needs in a variable in the script, or pass it in on the command-line.

Comment: FWIW, depending on your system, a script on your PATH _may_ be able to determine the full name of the directory it is stored in (no matter what your current directory is) by doing, eg `home=$(dirname $(readlink -e $0))`, but hopefully you shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: I can and I am aware of ways to get a bash script to use a directory. For exampe when running cron jobs I just cd into the desired directory. Problem is that this is hardcoded and I need to change it everytime I move to a new system. Was just wondering if there was a more elegant way so that I could combine everything into one file (executable) and just move that thing around anyway I want without having to change things every time.

Comment: You might be able to include your "resources" as here documents, depending on what you need to do with them.

Comment: This is basically what Docker and application containers in general do.